# Write function body

Tags: python-3.x

Write a Python3 function called addThenTriple which takes two arguments as input.  The function should add the arguments together and then triple the result (multiply by three) to calculate the output which is returned.

Test                           addThenTriple(2,3)
Result                           15

Comment: Suggestion: try first to research and post your own solution as well, this will improve your coding and search skill.

Answer (score -1):

The below function will take 2 parameters and then perform addition followed by multiplication with 3 for a triple.

```
def addThenTriple(a, b):
    addingResult = a + b
    return addingResult*3
    
print(addThenTriple(2, 3))
```

Comment: I believe, if someone marks as -ve they should provide feedback for the betterment of everyone, thanks.